# Making Hovered Image to Align Center

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I use the following css code to my html file, 
The Image that appears on the hover is ailgned in the top left, how can i make it centered?

Here is the html code

```
<a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb">View Sample
  <span>
    <img src="images/1.png" /><br>Simply beautiful.
  </span>
</a>
```

Here is the Css Code

```
.gallerycontainer{
position: relative;
/*Add a height attribute and set to largest image's height to prevent overlaying*/
}

.thumbnail img{

}

.thumbnail:hover{
background-color: transparent;
}

.thumbnail:hover img{

}

.thumbnail span{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
position: absolute;
background-color: #F0F0F0 ;
border-radius: 20px;
padding: 0px;


visibility: hidden;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}

.thumbnail span img{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
border-width: 10;

padding: 2px;
}

.thumbnail:hover span{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
visibility: visible;
top: 0;
left: 230px; /*position where enlarged image should offset horizontally */
z-index: 50;
}
```

Comment: Please create jsfiddle

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/93863/

Comment: Do you want the image to appear exactly in the middle of the screen even with resize??

Comment: Yes I just want to make the Image to be centered in the screen, even href is done on the bottom or anywhere in the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at my jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/93863/7/

css I have added: -

```
.thumbnail:hover span
{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -194px;    /* Half of the popups height */
    margin-left: -190px;   /* Half of the popups width */
}
```

Comment: The http://jsfiddle.net/Sulthan/93863/12/ Works, (The Image was centered when it was hovered at anywhere in the page.)

Comment: :) Glad you found a solution

Answer (score 0):

Change to `top: 50%;`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93863/4/)

```
.thumbnail:hover span{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
    visibility: visible;
    top: 50%;
    left: 230px; /*position where enlarged image should offset horizontally */
    z-index: 50;
}
```

Comment: But i want to make the image to be appeared to centered, wherever i use to make hover on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
.thumbnail:hover span{ 
visibility: visible;
top: 50%;
margin-top:-25%;
left: 230px; 
z-index: 50;
}
```

include "top:50%" and "margin-top:-25%" this will position it centrally.

Comment: If i place the href in the right most part of the screen it is making the image to appear from there, but i want to make the image to be appeared to centered, wherever i use to href.

Comment: I dont see this working. What is the purpose of showing the image on link hover? Is it a preview of an image??

Comment: Yes, i want to have an image preview once hovered on the text.